# Where to place my JDBC driver file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from this link: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors

Although the tutorial did mention the need for a JDBC driver for Redshift, but it didn't specify where to place the driver file. Currently when I run the script I'm getting the missing JDBC driver file error.

Comment: You need to give use more information in the question itself, don't make us go through that tutorial to find out what kind of project it is and where to place files. In general, you'd use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, and the driver would end up in the right place automatically.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC drivers are loaded during statup and better them to keep in class path.